# how do i get the venue details by user id for venues which user likes through foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

i want to get details of venue to users likes by user id.
i have UserId  and user likes different venue. by this UserId  i want to get details of venue in which user likes.
for example: i m user and i likes a venue in any city. now by my UserId i want to get details of that venue which i likes.
Is it possible by any query or foursquare API?

can i do something in this 
 https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/likes.

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand your question correctly, you want to find the venues a user likes?
That is not possible however, you can retrieve the likes for a particular venue.
For eh: If you make that query to a particular venue then it will return your friends who like that venue and the count of other people who like that venue.